# Why is my 3-way switch not operating?

Tags: electrical

[image]I am trying to install a Lutron LECL-153PH dimmer to a switch that has 4 places in room to turn on. I connected the 4 wires as shown. The lights will not turn on from the dimmer switch or dim. The lights will turn on from the two other locations.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide pictures of the old switch and the new one wired?

Comment: Are you sure you connected the common from the old switch to the black wire from the new switch?  The common wire is from the darker screw on your old switch, it's not necessarily in the same position as shown in your directions.

Comment: Top is the new one I hooked up. The bottom is the old 3 way. Maybe a reversed the red wires?

Comment: So are you sure you connected the wire that was under the black screw to the black wire from the dimmer?  Swapping the two reds shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the junction boxes involved please?

Comment: All we can see in the top picture is the factory wires running into the switch itself. We need to see which wires in the wall these have been connected to.

Answer (score 3):

Whichever wire went to the black screw before, needs to go to the black wire on the smart switch.  The 2 wires (travelers) which were on the brass screws, go to the red wires.

If you did not keep track of which ones those were, then ...

... well. Normally we strongly advise NOT to experiment by trying out different wire combinatations, because there are many combinations which will seem to work but then set up a dangerous situation that will kill you.  However in the case of a 3-way switch, where you are sure you are connecting the ground to grounds (green or bare), there is no particular problem with trying all 3 possibilities of where the switch black wire goes.

Just don't get accustomed to the idea of "experimenting with wire combinations" - because that is normally quite bad.